# How to use JSDoc to provide property types to styled.div?

Tags: styled-components

When I use VS Code, I can add a `jsconfig.json` file to get type assistance via IntelliSense. I'm not interested in switching to TypeScript, so I'm using JSDoc to annotate types where needed.

I found that I can add props to a given component like this:

```js
const StyledNode = styled(
  /** @type {React.ComponentType<React.ComponentProps<Box> & {level: number}>} */ (Box)
)`
  margin-left: ${p => p.level * 3}em;
`
```

This is zero-cost: I'm getting type assistance when using StyledNode as well as when using `level` in the CSS.

However, if I want to style a regular `div`, I have to do

```js
const StyledNode = styled(
  /** @type {React.ComponentType<React.DomAttributes & {level: number}>} */
  (React.forwardRef((p, ref) => <div ref={ref} {...p} />))
)`
  margin-left: ${p => p.level * 3}em;
`
```

which doesn't seem like zero-cost to me. The problem is that I can't see a way to pass the type parameter to `styled<type>` via JSDoc.

What is the most optimal way to provide the parameter types to the css template functions in `styled.div`?

Comment: I've been digging around on this for a while and haven't come up with a good solution. Have you found anything about this since posting?

Comment: Alas, nothing :(

Answer (score 2):

You can import `import * as CSS from 'csstype'` as global

and use jsdoc hack!

ex:
`@param {CSS.Property.FlexDirection} [props.flexDirection] - descriptions`

[image]
[image]

You can install the packages as Dev for avoid polluting, and using only inside jsdoc.

`npm i csstype -D -S`

is this help you ?

Comment: It's nice to use the CSS property types, but it doesn't help with typing the template functions. I would like the `${p => p.whatever}` functions in the styled CSS to have type support.

Comment: what about something like thats ? durty but work. 

``` function f(){ /**@param {React.CSSProperties} p*/ p => p.whatever}; ```

Comment: yes that should work, but you have to repeat it for every interpolation, which is very ugly. Better than nothing though, thanks.